# Connection refused Error when When tring to Run the Flutter Web App on Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I was trying to convert existing Mobile app to web using flutter web. I have enabled the web support and web folder also got created. I have tried to run the app on chrome browser using android studio run button.

[image]

Then I got this error and couldn't figure out how to fix this issue

```
SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = localhost, port = 62473
#0      _NativeSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:706:35)
#1      _RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1864:26)
#2      RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:27:23)
#3      Socket._startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2087:22)
#4      Socket.startConnect (dart:io/socket.dart:766:21)
#5      _ConnectionTarget.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2486:20)
#6      _HttpClient._getConnection.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2924:12)
#7      _HttpClient._getConnection (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2929:12)
#8      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2784:12)
#9      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2627:48)
#10     ChromeConnection.getUrl (package:webkit_inspection_protocol/webkit_inspection_protocol.dart:108:33)
#11     ChromeConnection.getTabs (package:webkit_inspection_protocol/webkit_inspection_protocol.dart:53:26)
#12     ChromiumLauncher._getFirstTab (package:flutter_tools/src/web/chrome.dart:436:41)
#13     ChromiumLauncher.connect (package:flutter_tools/src/web/chrome.dart:408:15)
#14     ChromiumLauncher.launch (package:flutter_tools/src/web/chrome.dart:233:12)
        <asynchronous suspension>
#15     ChromiumDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/web/web_device.dart:145:17)
        <asynchronous suspension>
#16     ResidentWebRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/isolated/resident_web_runner.dart:332:9)
        <asynchronous suspension>
#17     asyncGuard.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:111:24)
        <asynchronous suspension>

Unable to connect to Chrome debug port: 62472

SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = localhost, port = 62473
```

There are no issues on Flutter Doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.1, on macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-arm64 (Rosetta), locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

Devices

```
Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 119.0.6045.123
```

I also tried with deferent flutter channels. nothing works